# Set up Controller for AJAX

Tags: magento-2.1, ajax, http-request

I am currently developing a new module for my company on `Magento 2.1.8`.
The module requires the use of AJAX on the front end to send a receive data.

This is what i currently have in one of my controllers with the file path:

> Forum/Controller/Post/Message.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\Forum\Controller\Post;

class Message extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
        echo "Message returned from Controller Post/Message";
    }
}
?>
```

This does not seem to be returning anything other than a 404 error when I try to hit the page

**www.mywebsite.com/forum/post/message**

What am i doing wrong here?

thanks.

EDIT:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="forum" frontName="forum">
            <module name="VendorName_Forum" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: can you please share your routes.xml file ?

Comment: did you run setup:upgrade and clean cache after adding this code ?

Answer (score 0):

remove below code

```
$this->_view->loadLayout();
$this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
$this->_view->renderLayout();`
```

So your code will be like :

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\Forum\Controller\Post;        
class Message extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Message returned from Controller Post/Message";
    }
}

?>
```

Also check [How to create a basic module](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-create-helloworld-module/)